# Is this a good use/code of arrays with pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'd like to ask you if you think about this code, whether it is totally bad or i'm doing a bad use of the memory

This is the code

```
// Ask for capacity
int capacity ;
cout << "capacity: ";
cin >> capacity;

// Declare the array with pointers, this line is very important
int *arr = new int;

// For 0 until capacity-1 print ask for the numbers
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
  cout << "number: ";
  cin >> *(arr + i);
}

// Print them
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
  cout << "[" << i << "]: " << *(arr + i) << " in " << arr + i << endl;
}
```

And this is an example of its output

```
capacity: 9
number: 1
number: 2
number: 3
number: 4
number: 5
number: 6
number: 7
number: 8
number: 9
[0]: 1 in 0x55dee480c690
[1]: 2 in 0x55dee480c694
[2]: 3 in 0x55dee480c698
[3]: 4 in 0x55dee480c69c
[4]: 5 in 0x55dee480c6a0
[5]: 6 in 0x55dee480c6a4
[6]: 7 in 0x55dee480c6a8
[7]: 8 in 0x55dee480c6ac
[8]: 9 in 0x55dee480c6b0
```

Look that, effectively it's saving the numbers in the correct positions in memory (4 bits, the size of an int)
But what's the limit? How can I know if I'm touching memory that I shouldn't touch?
Because look that I'm declaring the array as

int *arr = new int

Is that okay?

the same with this code, but this could be a little bit worse because it's a string, an array of characters as you may know

```
// Declaring the pointer name as new char and ask for it
char *name = new char;
cout << "name in: ";
cin >> name;
cout << "name out\n";
for (int i = 0; *(name + i) != '\0' ; i++)
{
  printf("[%i]: %c\n", i, *(name + i));
}
```

Example:

```
name in: Gilberto       
name out
[0]: G
[1]: i
[2]: l
[3]: b
[4]: e
[5]: r
[6]: t
[7]: o
```

Comment: You allocated your array wrong. It should be `int* arr = new int[capacity];`

Comment: Sorry W.K.S, I'm very new here!

Comment: `int *arr = new int;` allocate a single `int` so the limit you are asking about in that case is 1. You can only access `arr[0]` and anything else is undefined behavior. The answer below shows how to allocate an array properly.

Comment: Would you be willing to use `std::vector` instead of arrays?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann mmm, I don't know about std::vectors ): where may I learn that? is that a better way?

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux, now I get it!

Comment: @W.K.S Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano I'd like to congratulate you on questioning the behavior you observed. Most new developers will accept that if it looks like it works it must be correct which is a dangerous approach to learning c++.

Comment: Ok @W.K.S I'm going to read about that, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thank you again @FrançoisAndrieux, I'm open to receive any suggestion and try to learn this correctly and effectively!

Comment: `std::vector<int> foo(vapacity);` ftw!

Comment: @Swordfish oh, what's that? I don't know what std::vector means, sorry!

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano I left some links in a reply to your comment on the answer of JesperJuhl.

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano cppreference is a good source for c++ information. It's [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) page contains an [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Example) of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The code only allocates one `int` object. Fix:

```
int* arr = new int[capacity];
```

---

`*(arr + i)` can be simpler: `arr[i]`.

---

The code needs to delete the array at the end:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Or, better, use a smart pointer to avoid having to delete manually:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[capacity]);
```

Or, even better, use `std::vector<int> arr(capacity);`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you, and how about the string? What if I want to allocate a string of just 10 chars or something like that, is that string of my code a string without limit? (in a way, and I know that's wrong)

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano Use `std::string` for strings.

Comment: Ohh, I don't know the last two ways that you recommend me, of course if they are better I need to learn them! But well, I'm still starting in all of this, thank you!

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano `new` and `delete` are interesting to understand but almost never used anymore in modern code. Prefer [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/containers) when you need to store several values or objects and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) when dealing with single objects.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm actually learning that because I read those topics in the program of my career, so I'll see C++ next year and I hope to know all these things before see them

Comment: By the way @MaximEgorushkin, if you do not mind, should I do the same with the 'string'?

Comment: For example char *name = new char[limit]

Comment: You can allocate a string with x characters by doing this

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  char firstname[12];
  cout << "Enter your first name" << endl;
  cin >> firstname;
  cout << firstname;
}

Comment: @Michelle doing what?

Comment: #include <iostream> #include <cstring> int main() { char firstname[12]; cout << "Enter your first name" << endl; cin >> firstname; cout << firstname; }

Comment: @Michelle oh, of course, but you're declaring the string as an array, and well, it's ok, but I want to learn and practice strings as pointers, that's why I coded it as I did

Answer (score 0):

Raw (owning) pointers and manual memory management is almost *never* a good idea in modern C++. You should use containers like `std::array` and `std::vector` rather than C-style arrays any day. And ownership and lifetime of dynamic resources is *much* better modeled with smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` & `std::weak_ptr` rather than raw pointers. Don't write code that's easy to get wrong. Use the facilities we have available, to write code that's easy to get *right* and *hard*(er) to get wrong.

Comment: Where may I learn about std::vectors? or std::unique_ptr and those things, and which are the better ways to do some things, they seem interesting and I still don't know them!

Comment: @Gilberto Marcano - https://en.cppreference.com/w/ is always worth a visit.

Comment: @GilbertoMarcano [std::unique_ptr](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-5-stdunique_ptr/), [std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/)